# How do I embed EPS into a PDF with PDF::API2?

Tags: perl, pdf, eps

Obviously, I want to avoid raster images as intermediate step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried this, but I think you'd have to first convert the EPS file to a PDF (using [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) or something), and then use `importPageIntoForm` or `importpage` (depending on exactly what you're trying to do).  You need a PostScript interpreter to handle EPS, because PostScript is a complete programming language, and PDF isn't.

Comment: Ghostscript also produces raster images in the PDF. It appears there is no converter that would output vector graphics usable in PDF. It's a shame that the fools at Adobe neglected to build in backward-compatibility into their new format. Thanks Adobe! >:( I'll accept you _pro forma_.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  It's my understanding that Ghostscript generates vector-based PDF.  (Obviously, if the EPS file contains raster images, they'll still be raster images in the PDF.)